# How can i improve this code to run faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making The Powder Toy in Python, and I encountered some problems. Firstly the code runs VERY slowly. I know the problem is in my main file: http://pastebin.com/bbQ4H4Xu. The other files are just detecting input / creating the 2d array, so the problem isn't there.

Within my main file, the problem seems to be in the method `updatescreen()`. How can I increase the performance of this function?

```
import pygame
#inputkey.py
from pygame.locals import *
def input_key():
global inputt
inputt = ""
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[K_q]:
    return 'q'
elif key[K_w]:
    return 'w'
elif key[K_e]:
    return 'e'
elif key[K_r]:
    return 'r'

#Createblocks.py
blocks = []
for i in range(400):
     blocks.append([])
          for j in range(400):
          blocks[i].append(0)
```

Comment: I don't know what this has to to with your toy, but it looks like you're trying to create a 400x400 matrix. If you want to perform numerical operations on n-dimensional arrays, you should have a look at [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). If you haven't heard of it yet, look it up right now. Extremely useful. Almost way to get around it if you use Python for  numerical stuff.

Comment: How big is the `Stone.png` image? The slowness is likely because you're potentially blitting it 2,500 times per screen update (as well as printing something).

Comment: Stone.png is a 1 px image, a gray hex

Answer (score 1):

Your `Main.py` file has a print statement in the loop:

```
def updatescreen():
    #The problem is here, it slows down the code.
    for i in range(windh):
        for x in range(windw):
            print x, i #          <== Here
            if not blocks[i][x] == 0:
                if blocks[i][x] == "Stone":
                    screen.blit(elementStone, (x,i))
```

presumably for debug? That's performing `windw` * `windh` = 2,500 print operations, which will slow the code down for sure. Try removing that and see how it improves.

Comment: yes it was an debug, the print x,i

Comment: f not blocks[i][x] == 0: is also redundant, by the looks of it. (Can't format code from phone)